# Django - print query result to html

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite, addition

I need some help with Django please.
I am working on a questionnaire. I made a raw query where I made a summation with two cells of the same row. I can't find the method to print it to my HTML.

**views.py**

```
def query(request):
my_query = Stressz_teszt.objects.raw('SELECT ID, stressz_v05 + stressz_v06 FROM stressz_stressz_teszt')
context = {
    'my_query': my_query,

}
return render(request, 'stressz/query.html', context)
```

**query.html**

```
{{ my_query }}

{% for i in my_query %}
    {{ i.stressz_company }} --- {{ user }} --- {{ summation here !!! }}

{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Stressz_teszt(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return self.stressz_name

user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
stressz_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Lorem ipsum")
stressz_company = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Lorem ipsum")
stressz_v01 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Lorem ipsum", null=True, blank=True)
stressz_v02 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Lorem ipsum.", null=True, blank=True)
stressz_v03 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Lorem ipsum", null=True, blank=True)
stressz_v04 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Lorem ipsum", null=True, blank=True)
stressz_v05 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Lorem ipsum", null=True, blank=True)
stressz_v06 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Lorem ipsum", null=True, blank=True)
```

...

`{{ my_query }}` just prints out my queryset:

```
<RawQuerySet: SELECT ID, stressz_v05 + stressz_v06 FROM stressz_stressz_teszt>
```

Thank you for your reply in advance!

Comment: can you share models.py?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code above.